Evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{n^2}{n^3+1}$

Evaluate $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{n^2}{n^3+1}$$

I was thinking of using telescopic method here but as the denominator is $n^3+1$, I highly doubt the usage of this method in this question. I cannot think of anything else.  Moreover, when I put this summand on wolframalpha, the answer I got made me believe that this is much more than a mere telescopic.
How to proceed? Any help is greatly appreciated.

$$\frac {n^2}{n^3+1} = \frac 1 3 \left(\frac{2n-1}{n^2-n+1}-\frac 1 {n+1}\right)$$
Thus
$$\begin{split}
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^n n^2}{n^3+1} &= \frac 1 3 \left(\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}  {n+1} + \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac {(-1)^n (2n-1)}{n^2-n+1}\right) \\
&=\frac 1 3 \left(\ln 2 -1 + \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac {(-1)^n (2n-1)}{\left(n-\frac 1 2\right)^2+\frac 3 4}\right) \\
\end{split}$$
where we have used that $$\ln(1+z) = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{(-z)^{n+1}}{n}$$
For the second sum, it is well-known that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}(2n-1)\pi}{\left(n-\frac 1 2\right)^2 \pi^2-z^2} = \sec(z)$$
Plugging in $z=i\frac{\sqrt{3}}2 \pi$ yields
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}(2n-1)}{\left(n-\frac 1 2\right)^2 +\frac 3 4} = -\pi\sec\left(i\pi\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)=-\pi\text{sech}\left(\pi\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)$$
Putting everything together
$$\boxed{\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^n n^2}{n^3+1}=\ln 2 -1 -\pi \text{sech}\left(\frac {\sqrt{3}}2 \pi\right)}$$
Edit: if you want to prove the formula for sec$(z)$, you can expand $\cos(st)$ in Fourier series for $|t|<\pi$, to obtain:
$$\cos{st} = \frac{\sin{\pi s}}{\pi s} \left [1+2 s^2 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1} \cos{k t}}{k^2-s^2} \right ]$$
and evaluate at $t=0$ and $s=\frac 1 2 -z$, and manipulate indices in the sum.

Ah well, you were faster and more concise, and you have a reference for the "well-known" formula (+1).

Great minds think alike.

We have $n^3 + 1 = (n+1)(n^2 - n + 1)$, and, for real constants $a,b,c$:
$$\begin{split}\frac{a}{n+1} + \frac{bn + c}{n^2 - n + 1} &= \frac{a(n^2 - n + 1) + (bn + c)(n + 1)}{(n+1)(n^2 - n + 1)}\\
&= \frac{(a+b)n^2 + (b + c - a)n + (a+c)}{(n+1)(n^2 - n + 1)}\end{split}$$
so that:
$$\frac{n^2}{n^3 + 1} = \frac{1}{a+b} \left(\frac{a}{n+1} + \frac{bn + c}{n^2 - n + 1} - \frac{(b - a + c)n + (a+c)}{(n+1)(n^2 - n + 1)}\right)$$
Now, we also have:
$$n^2 - n + 1 = \left(n - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 + \frac{3}{4} = \frac{1}{4}\left(\left(2n-1\right)^2 + 3\right)$$
and we have the following formula (apparently: that is, I'll assume it is true since it is featured on this Wikipedia page and lets us arrive to the conclusion of Wolfram in the body of the question. I have no idea how it is derived, I'm guessing a Fourier series formula applied to the correct function(s)?):
$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(2n-1)(-1)^{n}}{(2n-1)^2 + x^2} = -\frac{\pi}{4}\operatorname{sech}\left(\frac{x\pi}{2}\right)$$
We'll set $x = \sqrt3$ to fit our case, which means that we want $b = 2$ and $c = -1$. Thankfully, the system $b - a + c = a + c = 0$ is solved by $a = 1$ in this case, so that we finally have:
$$\begin{split}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n n^2}{n^3 + 1} &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \cdot \frac{1}{1 + 2}\left(\frac{1}{n + 1} + \frac{2n - 1}{\frac{1}{4}\left((2n-1)^2 + (\sqrt3)^2\right)}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{3}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n + 1} + 4\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(2n - 1)(-1)^n}{\left((2n-1)^2 + (\sqrt3)^2\right)}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{3}\left(\log(2) - 1 - \pi\operatorname{sech}\left(\frac{\sqrt3 \pi}{2}\right)\right)\end{split}$$

I didn't know about that Wiki page. It'll be helpful in the future. (+1)
